# Como colocar emoji em uma string?

Tags: python, string, unicode

Sei que em uma string posso colocar quaisquer caracteres que desejar, ex:

```
string = "qualquer coisa! @#$%ª太陽"
```

Mas e se eu quiser colocar um *emoji* em uma string, como faço? Tem alguma maneira específica?

Posso colocá-lo direto no código que funciona? Pois eu fiz isso e funcionou:

```
emoji = '' # criei uma string contendo um emoji
```

Isso está certo ou funcionou por coincidência? Caso não esteja, tem outra maneira de fazer?

Answer (score 8):

em Python a partir do "3" - , tudo internamente é unicode.  Unicode é traduzido por um "encoding' na hora dos dados serem enviados para uma API - em geral todas funcionam com "utf-8" . Utf-8 é um encoding específico que suporta todos os caracteres do Unicode (em contraste com o encoding nativo do Windows por exemplo, que só suporta 256 caracteres).

Em outras palavras: se você simplesmente colar o emoji entre aspas no seu código fonte, ele vai funcionar como qualquer outra string.
Se não quiser deixar emojis no seu código fonte, você pode deixa-los escapados no código fonte com a notação "\uXXXX" onde "XXXX" é o código do
unicode-codepoint do Emoji   - (por exemplo "\u263a" para "☺"). Se o código tiver mais de 5 dígitos, então é preciso usar `\U` maiúsculo e 8 dígitos: `"\U0001f389"` para ''. (não importa se são 5 dígitos - tem que ser 8 dígitos hexadecimais depois do `\U`: o que faltar deve ser completado com 0 a esquerda, como nesse exemplo)

Comment: se caso o code tiver 5X tipo esse u1F389

Comment: @PatrícioGabriel https://ideone.com/QdgCAu

Comment: atualizei a resposta com um exemplo de caracteres em que o codepoint precisa de mais que 4 dígitos hexa.

Comment: @PatrícioGabriel Inicialmente eu votei pra fechar porque não estava claro (pelo menos pra mim e para os demais) que vc só queria saber como colocar um emoji em uma string (afinal, a pergunta mencionava uma "tag", mas não tinha tag nenhuma no código). Talvez tenha sido preciosismo da minha parte, mas espero que entenda que a ideia do site é que as dúvidas também sejam úteis para futuros visitantes, por isso ela tem que estar muito clara, sem margem para dúvida ou interpretações. De qualquer forma, editei a pergunta e votei para reabrir...

Comment: ...veja se a dúvida era só essa mesmo (mas pelo *feedback* nesta resposta, parece ser). Outra dica é: se colocar "pesquisei e não achei", diga pelo menos o que vc pesquisou (afinal, uma pesquisa por "python string emoji" já traz vários resultados), e diga porque o que vc achou não serviu para o seu caso. Isso ajuda a focar a dúvida e evita o fechamento. O site pode parecer "hostil" no início, principalmente para quem não conhece o seu - complicado, admito - funcionamento, mas é com o objetivo de criar um repositório de conhecimento (é algo que vai além da "ajuda individual")...

Comment: ...Por vezes podemos errar e até exagerar na rigidez, mas é com a melhor das intenções. Enfim, agora só fica faltando um voto de reabertura, desculpe por qualquer inconveniente e espero que entenda que foi com a melhor das intenções. Por fim, fica a dica de ler [este guia](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/112052)